# Identifying Operations of a Process

Tags: java, process, subprocess, system, tasklist

I'm developing a system monitoring tool which shows processes and their operations. I was able to retrieve process list process id etc by executing **tasklist.exe**. Here is what i tried.

```
 try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\" + "tasklist.exe");
        BufferedReader input
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
        }

        input.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My Requirement is to find Operations of this process.
Please refer sample screenshot.

I've tried java api doc. There are 6 methods mentioned in api. But none of them giving information about sub processes or operations in a Process.

[image]

Just like in attached image i want to retrieve operation list of a task.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your best bet -- JNI or JNA, and then delving into and learning the appropriate API.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using Java. There is no method for this.

Comment: There must be at least third party libraries which does the task. Any ideas??